# Vector spherical harmonic expansion of a field

Tags: vectors, spherical-harmonics

For a scalar function defined on the surface of a unit sphere, it is easy to expand it in terms of spherical harmonics, with the algorithm clearly defined, eg on wikipedia. \
However, to investigate, say, shear wave velocity variations in 3D, apart from the velocity values in each direction on the unit sphere, I'd also need another UNIT vector specifying the polarisation of the wave at each direction. Scalar SH clearly are not able to do that, I've seen the concept of vector spherical harmonics which I think would enable the description I wanted, but the introductory materials are scarce to find. Could anyone please point out a way to incorporate the polarisation vector into the SH expansion for me, thanks very much!

Comment: "another UNIT vector specifying the polarisation of the wave at each direction" - I'm not familiar with that. I thought you would have one field for each polarisation state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KeithMcClary, and apologies for the confusion. Yes you're right, I need one field for each polarisation, but here I'm focussing on one shear component, and the other one can be treated the same afterwards. Basically I have a shear wave propagating in all directions in 3D, and what I would like to include in the SH expansion are the scalar velocity values (which are eigenvalues of a matrix) in all propagating directions, as well as the polarisation direction (which is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue) in each propagating direction. Does it make sense please?